# Is the sum of any column of transition matrix of Markov chain also equal to 1?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, machine-learning, markov-process

chapter 07 of the book "Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition" introduces this figure

[image]

the red rectangle is added by myself.

which take i = 1 for this formula

$\sum_{j=1}^m p_{ij} = 1, \quad \text{for all i}$

and gets

$\sum_{j=1}^m p_{1j} = 1$

the interpretation of which could be, current is at state 1, the probability that the next state is equal to j (1, 2, ..., m)

p11 represents from state 1 (time instant_1) to state 1 (time instant_2)

p12 represents from state 1 (time instant_1) to state 2 (time instant_2)

...

p1m represents from state 1 (time instant_1) to state m (time instant_2)

the sum of all the above p11+p12+...+p1m = 1

the question is how about the column one?

I guess p11+p21+...+pm1 is also equal to 1, is it?

Comment: No. Not in general. Column sums can also be $1$ but that is a special case. We say that the transition matrix is doubly stocastic in that case.

Comment: Consider the following markov chain with 2 states. State 1 leads to 1 with probability 1 and state 2 leads to state 1 with probability 1. Then the sums of the columns of the transition matrix are 2 and 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep reading, you'll find this example in the book "Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition"

"Alice is taking a probability class and in each week, she can be either up-to-date or she may have fallen behind. If she is up-to-date in a given week, the probability that she will be up-to-date (or behind) in the next week is 0.8 (or 0.2, respectively). If she is behind in the given week, the probability that she will be up-to-date (or behind) in the next week is 0.6 (or 0.4, respectively). We assume that these probabilities do not depend on whether she was up-to-date or behind in previous weeks, so the problem has the typical Markov chain character (the future depends on the past only through the present)..."

> And the key is here

"... let us introduce states 1 and 2, and identify them with being up-to-date and behind, respectively..." then the transition probability Matrix is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.8 & 0.2 \\
0.6 & 0.4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The sum of each row is 1, whereas the sum of column is not.